# I Hope You Like Connect Walls! #4

Tags: word, connect-wall

As in previous puzzles, you need to sort the following 16 words into 4 groups of 4 words; each group will have something in common, and all the common things relate to a tag.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hope | end | contact | fire |
| country | prince | tales | home |
| back | darkness | one | clones |
| stone | secrets | chest | pearl |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Final words from Pirates of the Caribbean movie titles: pearl, chest, end, tales
>  Final words from Star Wars movie titles: hope, back, clones, one
>  Final words from Star Trek movie titles: contact, home, country, darkness
>  Final words from Harry Potter movie titles: stone, secrets, fire, prince
>
>  The missing tag presumably is [movies](/questions/tagged/movies).

Comment: HOW DID YOU GET THIS SO QUICKLY AAAAARRRRGGGGHHHHH!!!! Now all you have to do is find the tag related to the puzzle.

Comment: @aguy *never underestimate the power of Puzzling* :P